# Show video capturing duration with AVCam

Tags: ios, video-capture, avcam

I'm using Apple's [AVCam source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avcam/introduction/intro.html)  to create a custom camera, I want still image and video capture both from custom camera, so for video capturing I'll also need video capture duration, not sure how it'll work? Any idea? I'll manage to add a `UILabel` and a `NSTimer` for this but don't know how I'll get exact video duration from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out with a `NSTimer`, when I start capturing I schedule a timer, and on stop capturing, I reset timer. In timer action, incrementing a duration ivar and showing it as capturing duration in a `UILabel`.